# How to display a UIViewController after auth request in swift UI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viewcontroller

I am trying to present a view controller after an auth request by passing in a view controller type into authState argument in SwiftUI View. "Cannot convert value of type 'MainView' to the expected argument type 'UIViewController,'" says the error message. How do I convert this MainView into view controller ?

```
struct MainView: View{
  
  let vc = MainView()
        appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow =
            OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: vc) { authState, error in
          if let authState = authState {
            // self.setAuthState(authState)
            print("Got authorization tokens. Access token: " +
                  "\(authState.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken ?? "nil")")
          } else {
            print("Authorization error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            // self.setAuthState(nil)
          }
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: Use `UIHostingController`

Comment: If your app is primarily SwiftUI and you're trying to present the OID controller, you'll likely need a UIViewControllerRepresentable to pass into it. This won't be `MainView` -- it'll probably be a controller you embed *in* `MainView`. See Apple's tutorials for integrating SwiftUI and UIKit